# Sending email on android via default email application

Tags: android, email, send

I am developing an android application that can send email. This following code lets me send email from my default gmail app on android device. I was wondering what the classes i should set so that i can send email from default android mail application?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" });
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("abc@gmail.com"));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "enter subject");
sendIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Insert text");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to. I am using following to send an email with default mail service.

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:info@yourcompany.com");
        Intent myActivity2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);                                   
                    myActivity2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Customer comments/questions");
        startActivity(myActivity2);
```